# scalacheck, scalatest, specs - which one has the lower barrier to entry?

Tags: testing, scala

Between the following test frameworks which one is the easiest to use and learn?

- [scalacheck](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/)
- [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/)
- [specs](http://code.google.com/p/specs/)

I'm using 2.8.0 and [sbt](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/) for building, so working nicely with it is a factor. I'm not necessarily looking at the most full featured. As best I can tell my criteria are in order:

- allow unit testing for Scala code
- painless set-up
- working with sbt
- tutorials
- rich documentation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I learned Scala by writing a suite of tests for my Java-based application. I used ScalaTest, and found it easy. I understand that ScalaTest offers a greater range of testing styles, including the Behavior-Driven Development (BDD) style employed by Specs. The greater scope of ScalaTest appealed to me because different styles lend themselves to different types of testing; for example, BDD is commonly used for unit testing, whereas the FeatureSpec style would be more appropriate for integration or acceptance testing.

Another consideration is support. Although I cannot speak for the Specs community, I can report that support from the author of ScalaTest has been quick, encouraging, and very useful.

Answer (score 6):

They all fit your requirements. Of the three, the one I think is weaker would be ScalaCheck -- weaker docs, less flexible, and different enough from traditional testing that there's more to learn. On the other hand, ScalaCheck is often used *with* ScalaTest or Specs, to complement their functionality with non-deterministic properties testing.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, specs is the most popular testing framework, and I think you should give it a try first, and see if it fits your job.

Works great with sbt with virtually no setup. Not sure how rich you want the documentation to be, but I was able to find most of the info from the website (start with [Quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/QuickStart)), and when I had problem people were helpful in the mailing list.